# Jackson Annotation to create local JSON References

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0

I have the following class structure

```
public class A {
    @Id
    public String id;


    public List<B> bs;
}

public class B{
    public String name;

    public List<B> preconditions;

}
```

If I return an instance of such a class then I get a nested `JSON` structure

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "bs": [
        {
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "name": "drilling",
            "preconditions": [
                {
                    "name": "abc"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to have that the preconditions become a list of references such as

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "bs": [
        {
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "name": "drilling",
            "preconditions": 
                    ["abc"]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do that? The preconditions should refer to the object in the list of `bs` I use `Jersey Web Serevices` and `Jackson` for the `JSON` generation.

**EDIT: based on Michał Ziober answer:**
It works fine, but if I change the order of the bs the result looks like the following:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "bs": [
        {
            "name": "drilling",
            "preconditions": 
                    [
                       {
                            "name": "abc"
                       }
                    ]
        },"abc"
    ]
}
```

I want to have that the objects are always defined in the bs list, not in the precondition list

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "bs": [
        {
            "name": "drilling",
            "preconditions": 
                    ["abc"]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JsonIdentityInfo` annotation. You `POJO` classes could look like below:

```
class A {

    private String id;

    @JsonIdentityInfo(property = "name", generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
    private List<B> bs;

    // getters, setters
}

class B {

    private String name;

    @JsonIdentityInfo(property = "name", generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
    private List<B> preconditions;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Simple example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        B b = new B();
        b.setName("abc");

        B b1 = new B();
        b1.setName("drilling");
        b1.setPreconditions(Arrays.asList(b));

        A a = new A();
        a.setId("3");
        a.setBs(Arrays.asList(b, b1));

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(a));
    }
}
```

prints:

```
{
  "id" : "3",
  "bs" : [ {
    "name" : "abc"
  }, {
    "name" : "drilling",
    "preconditions" : [ "abc" ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed solution. The given code works fine if the ordering of the list Bs ist [b,b1]. If I change that to [b1,b] than it looks like the following "bs":["abc",{"name":"drilling",preconditons:[{"name":"abc"}]}] I want  create arbitrary tree structures and so the object description should always be in bs list and not in preconditons